# OnCheckedChangeListener Not responding correctly

Tags: android, radio-group

I have set up 4 RadioButton's in an activity.

I'm having a problem where when I click on the "ALL" RadioButton, it shows the toast corresponding to the "CATEGORIES" RadioButton. Also, when I click on the "CATEGORIES" RadioButton, it displays the toast corresponding the "ABOUT" RadioButton. Then when I click on the "ABOUT" RadioButton, nothing displays.

I know it's something to do with some things not being directed correctly, but can't seem to find out what it is.

FYI: Later on I will be opening up activities with these RadioButtons, that's why I have't just done GetText and used just 1 OnCheckedChangeListener

Any help would be appreciated!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    RadioButton radioButton;
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);

    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnAllOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);

    radioButton
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnCategoriesOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCategories);

    radioButton
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnPopularOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPopular);

    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnAboutOnCheckedChangeListener);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
}

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnAllOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened ALL tab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

};

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnCategoriesOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened CATEGORIES tab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

};

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnPopularOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened POPULAR tab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

};

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnAboutOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened ABOUT tab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: try to use radio group if u want to select only one and use listener on radio group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Replace this code and try
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        RadioButton btnAll  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);
        btnCategories.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnAllOnCheckedChangeListener);

        RadioButton btnCategories  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCategories);
        btnCategories.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnCategoriesOnCheckedChangeListener);

        RadioButton btnPopular  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPopular);
        btnPopular.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnPopularOnCheckedChangeListener);

        RadioButton btnAbout = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btnAbout.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnAboutOnCheckedChangeListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You repeat the All radio button twice. The code should be:

```
RadioButton radioButton;
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);

radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnAllOnCheckedChangeListener);
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCategories);

radioButton
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnCategoriesOnCheckedChangeListener);
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPopular);

radioButton
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnPopularOnCheckedChangeListener);
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);

radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnAboutOnCheckedChangeListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

make single CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener in this way:

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                switch buttonView{
                case btn1:
    //your logic
    and so on
               }
            }

        };
```

and apply this listener for all your buttons